# xslt check first and last values in a tag are equal

Tags: xslt, substring

I have a XSL file contains coordinates similar to this:

```
<coordinates>
    12345,567,5
    56777,444,1
    67884,443,7
    12345,567,5
<coordinates>
```

Now I want to compare the first value of the coordinate with the last value (12345,567,5 must be equal to the last). How can I accomplish this with XSLT?

I already tried to split the values with substring() but the length of the coordinates is variable.

Comment: Which version of XSLT can you/do you use? Do you want to compare complete lines like  `    12345,567,5` or only numbers extracted from lines?

Comment: You need to start by tokenizing the string. This is easy in XSLT 2.0. Some XSLT 1.0 processors support this as an extension function. Otherwise you need to use a named recursive template (do a search, there are many examples).

Comment: Version 2.0 and i want a complete line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, use `tokenize` to find the lines and then compare:

```
<xsl:template match="coordinates">
    <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize(., '\r?\n')[normalize-space()]"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:sequence select="$lines[1] = $lines[last()]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

so for instance

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="coordinates">
        <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize(., '\r?\n')[normalize-space()]"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:sequence select="$lines[1] = $lines[last()]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

for e.g.

```
<body>
<coordinates>
    12345,567,5
    56777,444,1
    67884,443,7
    12345,567,5
</coordinates>
<coordinates>
    12345,567,5
    56777,444,1
    67884,443,7
    12345,567,6
</coordinates>
</body>
```

outputs

```
<body>
<coordinates>true</coordinates>
<coordinates>false</coordinates>
</body>
```

http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZN3/1